# Retrieve data from MySQL in Java (After end of result set error)

Tags: java, mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code here, and what is the best approach to do the same thing?

I'm trying to connect to a database and retrieve a list of unprocessed orders, recreate the order object which takes as parameters, a customer object, a product object, and an integer (unity).

These methods exist in my connection class:

```java
public Map<String, Cliente> loadCustomerList() throws SQLException {
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);
    Map<String, Cliente> listaClientes = new HashMap<>();
    query = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
    st = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String dni = rs.getString(1);
        String nombre = rs.getString(2);
        String apellidos = rs.getString(3);
        int descuento = rs.getInt(4);

        listaClientes.put(dni, new Cliente(dni, nombre, apellidos, descuento));
    }

    //conexion.close();
    return lista Clientes;
}

public List<Item> loadItemList() throws SQLException {
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);
    List<Item> listaItems = new ArrayList<>();
    query = "SELECT * FROM item;";
    st = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String nombre = rs.getString(1);
        double precio = rs.getDouble(2);
        int existencias = rs.getInt(3);

        listaItems.add(new Item(nombre, precio, existencias));
    }

    //conexion.close();
    return listaItems;
}

public Cliente findClient(String dni) throws SQLException {
    Cliente cliente = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Cliente> entry : loadCustomerList().entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(dni)) {
            cliente = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return cliente;
}
    
public Producto findItem(String nombreProduco) throws SQLException {
    Producto producto = null;
    for(Producto item : loadListItems()) {
        if(item.getNombre().equals(nombreProduco)) {
            producto = item;
        }
    }
    return producto;
}

public List<Pedido> loadOrderList() throws SQLException {
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);
    List<Pedido> listaPedidos = new ArrayList<>();
    Cliente cliente =null;
    Producto producto =null;
    query = "SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE `Numero Factura` IS NULL";
    st = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int unidad = rs.getInt(3);
         producto = findItem(rs.getString(2));
         cliente = findClient(rs.getString(6));
         listaPedidos.add(new Pedido(producto, unidad, cliente));
    }
    
    conexion.close();
    
    return listaPedidos;
}
```

I want to be able to call the loadOrderList() method in the constructor of the main operation class like this:

```
public class PruebaComercio {

    private Map<String, Cliente> listaClientes;
    private List<Pedido> listaPedidos;
    private List<Factura> listaFacturas;
    private Almacen almacen;
    private ConnectionMysql connection = new ConnectionMysql();

    public PruebaComercio() throws SQLException {
        this.listaClientes = connection.cargarListaClientes();
        this.listaPedidos = connection.loadOrderList();
        this.listaFacturas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.almacen = new Almacen();
    }
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:532)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:878)
    at Facturacion.ConnectionMysql.cargarListaPedido(ConnectionMysql.java:166)
    at Facturacion.PruebaComercio.<init>(PruebaComercio.java:23)
    at Facturacion.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Sorry for the use of Spanish here, the project was done in Spanish, I did my best to translate the important things.

Comment: _Observation_ You are creating a connection for each method that requires DB access, Better to make one connection and reuse it in whichever method requires db access. Your way risks running out of connections

Comment: Also, `st` and `rs` seem to be fields. Very bad idea.

Comment: The point here was to be able to close the connection aswell  because these methods are called in the constructor and there is no other way to go about it, but as you can see I had to comment out the close() because the way I set this up  back fired in the loadOrderList() method, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadOrderList` calls (indirectly) `loadItemList` which changes the `st` and `rs` fields while `rs` is still needed in `loadOrderList` for the next iterations.

Comment: You are right I had to create a new ResultSet field in the loadOrderList() method, so far the error has disappeared.